Radon transform over a rhombus
My following question is related to an integral over a rhombus $|x|+|y| \leq 1$
$$
I = \int^1_{-1}dy\int_{-(1-|y|)}^{1-|y|}dx\ \delta(r-y-x z)\sum_{n,m}p_{mn}x^m y^n\,,
$$
where $m\in\{0,2,4,...\}$, $n\in\{1,3,5,...\}$, $m+n\leq N$ (odd integer), and $r,z$ and $p_{mn}$ are some real-valued parameters.
If I consider the case $r<-z$ and $z\geq 0$, integrating wrt $x$ allows for the substitution $x\to (r-y)/z$ as long as this value falls within the limits of integration. To impose that we can restrict the integral wrt $y$ to the interval $y\in(y_2,y_1)$ where:
\begin{equation}
    \left.\begin{aligned}
        y_1 & = \frac{r+z}{1-z}\\
        y_2 & = \frac{r-z}{1+z}
    \end{aligned}\right\}\,.
\end{equation}
Using Newton's binomial I get (for $r<-z$, $z\geq 0$):
$$
I = \sum_{m,n}p_{mn}\sum_{k=0}^m \begin{pmatrix}m\\k\end{pmatrix} \frac{r^{m-k}}{z^{m+1}} (-1)^k\frac{1}{k+n+1}\left[ \left(\frac{r+z}{1-z}\right)^{k+n+1} - \left(\frac{r-z}{1+z}\right)^{k+n+1} \right]\,. \tag 1
$$
I've been told this integral can be written as
$$
I = \sum_{a=1}^{N+1}\sum_{b=0}^{N+1}\left[\frac{1}{(1+z)^a} + \frac{1}{(1-z)^a} \right]\sum_{m,n}p_{mn}\mathbb{M}_{mnab}r^{b}\,, \tag 2
$$
with
$$
\mathbb{M}_{mnab}=\sum_{c=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{a+b+c}}{m+c+1}\begin{pmatrix}n\\c\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c\\m-a+c+1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}m+c+1\\b-n+c\end{pmatrix}
$$
I tried using Newton's binomial in the square brackets of Eq. (1), but I couldn't read out the structure given in Eq. (2). Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?
